# Prevent Duplication in Solr using UpdateRequestProcessor chain

Tags: solr

We are using Solr to store items that have been received and ingested through another service.

I am currently looking into a task to avoid duplicate items being created with the same id.

I am not an expert in Solr and trying pick up the task from someone who has left the company. The last suggestion about how to prevent duplication mentioned that it should be possible using a combination of defining unique id on the id field and using UpdateRequestProcessor chain. I don't know enough about the UpdateRequestProcessor chain to know the approach in mind. I know the ultimate goal was that when an item was sent to Solr with the same id as an existing id then an update would be performed rather than a create.

I have looked at Solr documentation about the UpdateRequestProcessor chain. Without more background information, those resources have not helped that much so far. I think I would benefit from Solr experts to help me get started or pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get a URP involved. It is much simpler than that. If your doc's id (defined in `schema.xml` as `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`
) is already an unique id, then, you don't need to do anything else. Indexing the same doc with same id twice will update it the second time (delete and new insert under the hood).

If your `uniqueKey` is not the unique id, then just rework the schema (and the app using Solr if it needs to), so they match.